# Yii - findAll with order by

Tags: php, yii

How to findAll with specific column with order by desc ?

**Code bellow worked and find all from the developer id**

```
$id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
$models = Games::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);
```

**Code bellow worked and ordered**

```
$models = Games::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'status'));
```

**When I mixed together then only worked for findAll developer_id='.$id doesn't order by**

```
$id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
$models = Games::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id,array('order'=>'status'));
```

Any suggestion to do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your model, add this function:

```
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'bystatus' => array('order' => 'status DESC'),
    );
}
```

Now you can do the query like this:

```
$models = Games::model()->bystatus()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);
```

=====

Bonus: You can also add this function in your model:

```
public function bydeveloper($devId) {
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'condition' => 'developer_id = '.$devId,
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Now you can do the query like this:

```
$models = Games::model()->bystatus()->bydeveloper($id)->findAll();
```

Comment: do not have a method or closure named "bystatus".

Comment: You have to add the scopes method to the Games model, not controller.

Comment: thanks !! if I have 3 status : new, reject, resubmit ... i want to order resubmit first then reject then new ... how to do ?

Comment: Scopes are no longer supported in Yii2. You should create your own function to handle this. See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#customizing-query-classes (very end of this section, blue footnote)

Comment: @WadeShuler This is a question that is regarding Yii 1, and was posted years ago. The answer is not wrong in its context. The newer questions are tagged `yii2`. Your downvote was uncalled for.

Comment: 'status DESC' does NOT work.  Yii ignores the order by part.

Comment: @WadeShuler so you assume that anyone having an active project on Yii 1 will immediately (or at all!) swap to Yii 2? I have an active Yii 1 project, and I did find this very useful for me, so should I (and anyone else like me) just be without help because there is a new version to Yii...?

Answer (score 10):

you can try this -

```
$id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');

$model = Games::model()->findAll(array("condition" => "developer_id = '".$id."'","order" => "status"));
```

its should be work

Answer (score 1):

You can try use criteria:

```
$id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('developer_id',$id);
$criteria->order='status DESC';

$models = Games::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way but you can do:

```
$models = Games::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id.' order by status DESC');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try to do like this:

Model::find()->where([['attribute'=>'value']])->orderBy(['attribute'=>SORT_DESC])->all();

Comment: Don't simply leave a line of code as an answer, even if it's correct, rather help explain how or why this might solve the problem and what it does.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).