# Order by related data doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have model with relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'fidistr' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Distributors', 'fidistr_id', 'order'=>'fsname'),
        'fitown' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Town', 'fitown_id'),
        'distributorsPointMails' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'DistributorsPointMail', 'fidistr_point_id'),
        'distributorsPointPhones' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'DistributorsPointPhones', 'fidistr_point_id'),
    );
}
```

I would like to order data by "fsname" from related table.  I tried this:

```
$models = DistributorsPoint::model()->findAll('fitown_id=:id', array('id' => $_POST['city_id']));
```

but it still returns unsorted data. Help please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964641/yii-findall-with-order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order` on the relation is only used when lazy loading the relation. [From the Yii guide on relations:](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options)

> Note: when using eager loading such relation options as 'order',
>   'group', 'having', 'limit' and 'offset' will be ignored. You should
>   setup such parameters at the main model criteria level if you wish
>   them to be applied.

You can pass a criteria array instead of a string as the first parameter of [`findAll()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail). This will be used to initialize a `CDbCriteria` object. To order by a relation you need to [eager load](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query) the relation using [`with()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail):

```
$models = DistributorsPoint::model()
    ->with('fidistr')
    ->findAll(array(
        'condition' => 'fitown_id=:id',
        'order'     => 'fidistr.fsname',
        'params'    => array(':id' => $_POST['city_id'])
   ));
```