# Yii:Get the user submitted data in DESC order

Tags: php, yii

I am yiibie. In my project user has the privilege write to stories in which the user writes a title and story and submits. The story gets posted on the page but the latest story(which the user has written) comes at the bottom, I want that whenever a story is written it comes at the top, I mean story comes in the DESC order.
Here is what i have done in my `view file` and the `story controller create function` 
This is the code for my view file

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'story-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
// There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<div class="content">
<div class="banner">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/story-banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div><!--banner ending here--><br>
<div class="story-content">


<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 vol-stories" style="background-color: #CCFFCC; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<div class="media">
<div class="media-left">
<a href="user-profile.php">
<?php 
foreach($allmodels as $model)
{
?>
<img class="media-object" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseurl;?>/img/<?php //echo $model->Profile->picture;?>">
</a>
</div>
<div class="media-body"><strong><?php echo $model->user->username?></strong> <!--username will come here-->

<h4 class="media-heading"><strong><br><?php echo $model->title?></strong></h4>
<p style="color:black; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px"><?php echo $model->story?> <hr style="border-color: #666666"></p>
<?php
}
?>
</div>

</div><!--Media ending here--> 
</div>
</div><!--row ending here--><br>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<hr>

<div class="write-story" style="background-color: #80B098;">


<form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/story/create" method="POST">
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'title',array('maxlength'=>100)); ?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'story',array('maxlength'=>1000)); ?>
    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>

</div><!--row ending here-->
<br>
</div><!--write-story ending here-->
<br>


</div><!--content ending here-->


</div><!--container ending here-->
```

And this is the code for my `storycontroller`

```
<?php

class StoryController extends RController
{
    /**
    * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
    * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
    */
    public $layout='//layouts/admin';

    /**
    * @return array action filters
    */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
//          'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
//          'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
                    'rights',
        );
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the access control rules.
    * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
    * @return array access control rules
    */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Displays a particular model.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
    */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }
//public function actionAllstory() //This has been added to view all the stories on the  stories page
//  {
//               $this->layout='main';
//      $this->render('allstory');// yeh wala tariqa mujhay pogo ne bataya tha
//  }
        public function actionAllstory() //This has been added to view all the stories on the  stories page
{

     $allmodels =  story::model()->findAll();
     $this->layout='main';
     $this->render('allstory', array('allmodels' => $allmodels));
}


    /**
    * Creates a new model.
    * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Story;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Story']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Story'];

                        $model->user_id=Yii::app()->user->id;//This will get the id of the logged in user..!!

            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('story/allstory'));// Seen from stackoverflow so becuse it was not going to the correct url
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Updates a particular model.
    * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
    */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Story']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Story'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Deletes a particular model.
    * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
    */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
        {
            // we only allow deletion via POST request
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    /**
    * Lists all models.
    */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Story');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Manages all models.
    */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new Story('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Story']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Story'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
    * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
    * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
    * @return Story the loaded model
    * @throws CHttpException
    */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Story::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
    * Performs the AJAX validation.
    * @param Story $model the model to be validated
    */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='story-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii - findAll with order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964641/yii-findall-with-order-by)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This in Model:-

 return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => array(
                'defaultOrder' => 't.created_on DESC', //created_on or your primary key which is auto increment
            ),
        ));
```